# PostgreSQL - How to change superuser to nosuperuser?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, alter, superuser

I have a role:

```
CREATE ROLE x LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '....'
  SUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

This role is already created.

I want to modify it to:

```
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

Change the `SUPERUSER`  to `NOSUPERUSER` ;

Is it possible to do it without doing `Drop role` ?

Comment: just`alter user su nosuperuser;` ?..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html

> ALTER ROLE role_specification [ WITH ] option [ ... ]
>
> where option can be:
>
> ```
>   SUPERUSER | NOSUPERUSER
> ```

```
t=# create user su superuser;
CREATE ROLE
t=# \du+ su
                  List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of | Description
-----------+------------+-----------+-------------
 su        | Superuser  | {}        |

t=# alter user su nosuperuser;
ALTER ROLE
t=# \du+ su
                  List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of | Description
-----------+------------+-----------+-------------
 su        |            | {}        |
```

or with optional WITH:

```
t=# alter user su with nosuperuser;
ALTER ROLE
```

Comment: I tried to to it with SET command ... this approach was not mentioned here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterrole.html   Thank you